# Why Can't I connect to AWS RDS instance with Dropwizard?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, dropwizard

I've got a simple Dropwizard API right now with one endpoint to return all Users in my AWS RDS database, and one "hello world" endpoint. I can connect to my RDS instance with MySQL Workbench on my dev machine, so I know the connection is allowed.

My App builds and initially runs fine. I have a "hello world" endpoint which is working, but when I try and hit my `/users/all` endpoint, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [2016-05-01 23:47:07,305] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: b92c1a9ace3378bf
! java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
! at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1327)
! ... 66 common frames omitted
```

I believe I am using the `1.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT` Dropwizard version from [Sonatype Nexus Snapshots](http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots).

In my config.yml, I have:

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: <my_user>
  password: <my_password>
  url: jdbc:mysql://<my_db>.blah.rds.amazonaws.com
```

My Configuration class is very simple, and is limited to the following.

```
public class AppConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

    @JsonProperty("database")
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }

}
```

And my Service run method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void run(AppConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {

    environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    environment.jersey().register(new AppResource());

    /* initialize DB and DAOs */
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql");

    final UserDAO userDAO = jdbi.onDemand(UserDAO.class);

    /* Initialize Resources */
    final UserResource userResource = new UserResource(userDAO);
    environment.jersey().register(userResource);

}
```

I've tried debugging the application while running, and see that my `userDAO` object has been created. I tried digging around the instance variables/functions, but I couldn't find any useful information explaining why it was not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't specifying a database correctly in the JDBC URL. Look at the format specified [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):
`jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]]`

Comment: It looks to me like the only difference is that I'm not providing a port number. For this, I'm using the default port so it shouldn't matter. I'll try this later just to make sure, but was that what you thought wasn't correct?

Comment: The error message is specifically saying you didn't specify a database. If you look at the JDBC URL syntax, you specify the database after the host, like this: `jdbc:mysql://host:port/database` Your JDBC URL is missing the `/database` portion.